# Append element in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I dont understand why my jquery does not append an element to my web page

here is the code

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $(function() {
         $("#button<?php echo $data['id']; ?>").click(function(e) {
--> Append          $(this).append("<p id='xxxx'> </p>");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('post/create'); ?>",
                        success: function(data) {

                            $("#xxxx").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
                 });
        });
    </script>
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: add your generated html also

Comment: Why do you have `$(function...)` inside `$(document).ready(function(...))`? The both bind the document ready handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need `after()` as button wont be containing `p` as input type="button" is not a container control.

```
$(this).after("<p id='xxxx'> </p>");
```

You can use  tag that can contain `p` if you want

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/5LVAT/)**

HTML

```
<div>
     Div containing button tag
    <button  id="buttoncontrol" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#buttoncontrol').append("<p>this is p</p>");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works.   For my understanding, why append did not work? @Ail

Comment: append makes the element child of the given element and input button can not have child

Answer (score 0):

`<button></button>` doesn't contain p element like this `<button><p>your para</p></button>`

So, you might be trying to do append text like this:

```
$(this).text("your_text");
```

Or, you want to append after the button then you could do this:

```
$(this).after('<p id="xxxx" />');
```

Or, like this:

```
$('<p id="xxxx" />').insertAfter($(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#button<?php echo $data['id']; ?>").click(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('post/create'); ?>",
            success: function (data) {
                $this.after("<p id='xxxx'>" + data + "</p>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Since `<button>` cannot contain `<p>` element, you need to add your paragraph after your button instead.

Also, you just need one DOM ready handler `$(function() {...});`.